# mySql difference performance in a where query

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a table with 95084 rows. I found this two perfomance differences:

`EXPAIN SELECT * FROM sensor WHERE fecha >= '2022-07-16 10:00:00';` It requires 32 rows.

`EXPAIN SELECT * FROM sensor WHERE DATE(fecha) = '2022-07-16' AND HOUR(fecha) >= '10:00:00';` That grows up to 95084 rows.

How Mysql works in that way and why this difference?. Thank you

Comment: Your second query is "non-sargable", by using the functions `date,hour` you are forcing the engine to scan every row; it doesn't know the result of the function fulfills the predicate until it checks each value.

Comment: In the second query you tell Mysql to get the Hour from field fecha and so MySQL does it. It gets fecha with the function HOUR() and compaire the result with '10:00:00'. Mysql must do this for each row. And so it is a full table scan. MySQL cant use a INDEX. So its never a god idea to have a function in WHERE on a field

Comment: Perhaps, instead of, "requires" and "grows", you mean "uses" or "accesses"?

Comment: They don't return the same results.  '2022-07-17 09:00:00' will be included in the first SELECT, but not the second.